# Flutter how to show container line wise in column

Tags: flutter

I have 3 container in a column i need to show first 2 container in middle and the 3rd in last on the screen

Something like this

[image]

my code is this

```
return Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        width: stackWidth * 0.75,
                        child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png')),
                    Container(
                      color: Color(0xffff4b4b),
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            'Only for LunchBox management',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                          )),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Text(
                            'Powered by LunchBox KSA',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                          )),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
```

Its showing in column but i need to show first 2 container of column in middle and third in last

Comment: Did you try Stack and position?

Comment: `Column[Expanded, Container1, Container2, Expanded, Container3]`

Comment: or even better `Spacer`: like this: `body: Column(
children: [
Spacer(),
Container(height: 20, color: Colors.red),
Container(height: 20, color: Colors.green),
Spacer(),
Container(height: 20, color: Colors.blue),
],
),`

Comment: Use stack widget for more beatiful outlook

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                const Spacer(),  // <---- New
                Container(
                    width: stackWidth * 0.75,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png')),
                Container(
                  color: Color(0xffff4b4b),
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: Text(
                        'Only for LunchBox management',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                      )),
                ),
                const Spacer(), // <---- New
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: Text(
                        'Powered by LunchBox KSA',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                      )),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please use this!
>
> ```
> return Scaffold(
>       backgroundColor: Colors.black,
>       body: Center(
>         child: Column(
>           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
>           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
>           children: <Widget>[
>             Container(
>               color: Colors.white,
>               width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
>               height: 80,
>               alignment: Alignment.center,
>               child: Text(
>                 "YOUR LOGO",
>                 style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
>               ),
>             ),
>             SizedBox(height: 10),
>             Container(
>               color: Color(0xffff4b4b),
>               child: Padding(
>                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
>                   child: Text(
>                     'Only for LunchBox management',
>                     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
>                   )),
>             ),
>           ],
>         ),
>       ),
>       bottomNavigationBar: Row(
>         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
>         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
>         children: [
>           Container(
>             child: Padding(
>                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
>                 child: Text(
>                   'Powered by LunchBox KSA',
>                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
>                 )),
>           ),
>         ],
>       ),
>     );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

\ **

- it may be help you

**

```
body: Container(
          child: Column(
              children: [
             Expanded(
            flex: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: 80,
              color: Colors.green,
            )),
        Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              height: 150,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Image.asset("assets/github.png"),
            )),
        Expanded(
            flex: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: 80,
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: Text(
                        "Git Hub Power",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                      ))),
            )),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```